# Android. Xiaomi (android 10+) mode_night_follow_system wrong color when phone system theme is dark

Tags: android, darkmode, xiaomi, android-dark-theme, android-darkmode

the problem is:

When I open the application, I set the theme according to the theme of the device. In android code it is = mode_night_follow_system.

Let's imagine that the theme of the system(device) is dark.
When logging into the mobile app, I do

```
  AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(mode_night_follow_system)
```

The application changes the color to dark, but it feels like it does not take my colors indicated in color-dark.

**The problem is only for xiaomi phones with android 10+**

On other models Samsung, Huawei, etc., there are no problems.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same issue this solved my problem Speciall the second option.

1)Add this line in each activity just below onCreate

```
AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
```

**OR**

2. add this line in your themes under style section

```
<item name="android:forceDarkAllowed" tools:targetApi="q">false</item>
```

Comment: in my project i have dark theme support(mode_night_follow_system). And I need it to be painted dark if the divice theme is dark.
On all devices it paints correctly, with the exception only on xiaomi

Comment: android:forceDarkAllowed what does it do?

Comment: <item name="android:forceDarkAllowed" tools:targetApi="q">false</item>

helps me. Thank you